# What are good resources to study the Abhidhamma of Central/South Asia Schools (e.g. Sthaviravāda, Sarvāstivāda, Dharmaguptaka, Mūlasarvāstivāda, etc.)

Tags: reference-request, abhidhamma

What are good resources and references (ideally online) to learn Abhidhamma from school of Buddhism in Central/South Asia (Sthaviravāda, Theravada, Sarvāstivāda, Dharmaguptaka, Mūlasarvāstivāda, etc.).

*NB: I am aware of BPU BPhil 3rd Year Lecture Notes. So I am looking for resource other than this.*

Comment: There is an accepted answer below, but do not consider the question closed. If anybody finds anything else please post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found:

- [Series of audio lectures on Sarvastivada Abhidharma](http://sarvastivadaclass.blogspot.com/2008/09/sarvastivada-abhidharma-audio-slide.html) with
  [accompanying slides](http://sarvastivadaclass.blogspot.com/2008/09/sarvastivada-abhidharma-resources.html) by Bhikkhu Dhammajoti.
- [Sarvastivada Abhidharma](http://yun.baidu.com/share/link?uk=1010824064&shareid=1834626164&third=1&adapt=pc&fr=ftw), book by Bhikkhu Dhammajoti.

Also see [this question and answer by RobM](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/text-request-abhidhamma) for a link to Bhikkhu Bodhi's "Comprehensive Manual of Abhidhamma" downloadable as PDF.

Comment: If you find any more material please keep posting.

Comment: I am wondering if there Sarvastivada Abhidharma 4th expanded edition online